# How to Connect R to Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, r

I need to connect R to oracle and I have been unsuccessful so far. I downloaded two packages: RODBC & RODM.

This is the statement that I've been using:

```
DB <- odbcDriverConnect("DBIORES1",uid="mhala",pwd="XXXXXXX")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in odbcDriverConnect("DBIORES1", uid = "mhalagan", pwd = "XXXXXXX") : 
  unused argument(s) (uid = "mhalagan", pwd = "XXXXXXX")
```

What information do I need to be able to connect to an oracle database? Am I using the correct package?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097850/connecting-to-oracle-10g-database-through-r

Answer (score 4):

See the help page for `odbcDriverConnect()`. `odbcDriverConnect()` does not accept `uid` or `pwd` arguments.  You probably meant to use `odbcConnect()` instead:

```
odbcConnect(dsn = "DBIORES1", uid = "mhala", pwd = "XXXXXXX")
```

In addition to the `RODBC` package, there is the `RODM` package, which I believe is specifically designed for Oracle databases and is further described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/saternos-r-161569.html .  I do not use Oracle databases, so cannot comment on advantages of the two packages.

Answer (score 3):

RJDBC worked just fine for me. You just need to have Oracle-thin driver jar file and configure the connection like:

```
> install.packages("RJDBC")
> library(RJDBC)
> drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver","/path/to/driver/com/oracle/oracle-thin/11.2.0.1.0/oracle-thin-11.2.0.1.0.jar”)
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@database:port:schema”, “user”, “passwd”)
```

and then is ready to perform some queries.

JA.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the oracle ODBC client/driver? You will need that if you are going to use the ODBC R package.  Go to [oracle instant client download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) get the client for your OS.  install them and then proceed to configure the ODBC and test the connection outside of R then install the R and RODBC and test inside R.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success in the past connecting to Oracle databases from R with RJDBC.  I found it easier to get going as I just grabbed the connection string that I'd used successfully inside the java based GUI I was using at the time and like magic it "just works"(tm).