# Creating R script in web app and execute it against remote database

Tags: java, r, oracle

I have java/JSF web app. I have to make possible creation of custom R script in app, and it's execution on remote Oracle DB with Oracle R Enterprise. I don't even understand the concept. Can a R script be sent to remote DB for execution? If anyone dealt with Oracle R Enterprise could he/she give me some pointers or basic understanding and some links would be appreciated?

Comment: this might be worth a read http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/lectures/SQL-R.pdf

Comment: or this https://science.nature.nps.gov/im/datamgmt/statistics/r/fundamentals/index.cfm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037195/how-to-connect-r-to-oracle

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-R-Language-to-Connect-with-an-ORACLE-Database

Comment: @RachelGallen - the OP is talking about running a script on Oracle's embedded R technology: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are short instructions:

On server(if DB is on another computer):
Install R language,
Install Oracle R Enterprise

On client(if not working on computer with DB installed on it):
Install r language
Install oracle instantClient and set PATH(Win) to folder
Install support-client libraries
Install client libraries,
see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36939_01/doc/doc.13/e36763/client.htm
for specifics.

Then connect to DB(with ORE installed) through your app/R/R-Studio/SQLDeveloper and use R-interface or SQL-interface(depending on your medium for connecting to DB)

I recommend going through these 8 flash lectures from oracle:
www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial/db/ore1.1/ore_part1/player.html
www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial/db/ore1.1/ore_part2/player.html
www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial/db/ore1.1/ore_part3/player.html
...
                                                                            www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial/db/ore1.1/ore_part8/player.html