# Connecting to oracle 10g database through R

Tags: sql, r, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

I want to import data from SQL databases through R.I tried too many times(almost 6 hrs) connecting to the server. I ran these command and it shows error:-

> jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="ojdbc6.jar")
>
> jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database.desktop-65l5f3s:1521/orcl", "username", "password")
>   Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified

I think there is a problem of driver but I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: Can you connect to your Oracle database via the desktop client?  See if you can rule out a problem with Oracle.

Comment: The error suggests that the name `database.desktop-65l5f3s` doesn't exist in the DNS.  Can you ping `database.desktop-65l5f3s` from your machine?

Comment: Thank you for response...  but I don't know how to ping database.desktop-65l5f3s from machine.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I did to connect R to the Oracle database

1. Download the Oracle driver JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. Install RJDBC

then run the code below in r

```
library(RJDBC)
## Loading required package: DBI
## Loading required package: rJava
# specify the driver type and location in your machine

jdbcDriver = JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                  classPath="C:/app/techsupport/product/11.2.0/client_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar") # may be different on your machine, it's based on your JDK installation

# connect to the database

conn = dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database.hostname.com:port/service_name",  # get the database name, port, and service name from you DBA
             user = YourUserName,
             password = YourPassword)

# get office table using a query string

startTime <- Sys.time() # start timer
OfficeTable = dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from office")
# disconnect after working with database
dbDisconnect(conn)
## [1] TRUE
Sys.time() - startTime  # calc time to import table
## Time difference of 0.1630161 secs
# take a look at the data
str(OfficeTable)
## 'data.frame':    373 obs. of  22 variables:
```